# Is it possible in Spring MVC to have void handlers for requests?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Is it possible in Spring MVC to have void handler for request?

Suppose I have a simple controller, which doesn't need to interact with any view.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/cursor")
public class CursorController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = PUT)
    public void setter(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        AnswerController.setCursor(id);
    }
}
```

*UPD*

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/cursor")
public class CursorController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<String> update(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        AnswerController.setCursor(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Short answer is yes, but why would you not want to at least send back a simple 200 response to notify you got the request?

Comment: like in my update for the question? Maybe it's a good idea, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can `return void`, then you have to mark the method with

`@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)` you don't need `@ResponseBody`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateSomeData" method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public void defaultMethod(...) {
    ...
}
```

Only get methods return a `200 status code` implicity, all others you have do one of three things:

Return void and mark the method with `@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)`

Return An object and mark it with `@ResponseBody`

Return an `HttpEntity` instance

Also refer this for [interesting information](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/08/spring-mvcs-default-behavior.html).

Comment: I would return HTTP 204 No Content